# Streamlining Powershell based file edition

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

So I currently have a group of csv files that I comb through and replace various portions of using powershell. However, the current process I use is highly time intensive, and I was wondering if there was a better more streamlined solution.

Current code: (This is all contained in a for each loop, where $file is the file location and $tb is the name of a table)

```
Invoke-sqlcmd -query "select Distinct * from $($tb.name) WITH (NoLock)" -server server -database database | Export-CSV $file -Delimiter "|" -Encoding "Unicode" -NoTypeInformation
(get-content $file) -replace '"?\|"?', "|" | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace '\|true\|', '|1|' | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace '\|false\|', '|0|' | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace '^"' | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace '"$' | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace '^true\|', '1|' | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace '^false\|', '0|' | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace 'true$', '1' | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace 'false$', '0' | select -Skip 1 | out-file $file
(get-content $file) -replace '\|false\|', '|0|' | out-file $file
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upvoted answer by @EBGreen, that's probably the solution. Just to show you how to do it (and how to chain operators), I'll add the code:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd...
(get-content $file) -replace '"?\|"?', "|" `
                    -replace '\|true\|', '|1|'`
...
                    -replace '\|false\|', '|0|' | out-file $file
```

Besides that consider replacing earlier before you export the data as csv. You may go through the collection from `Invoke-SqlCmd` and replace appropriate property values. 
Also consider if simply replacing `true` with `1` and `false` with `0` would remove most of the regexes.

Comment: +1 - I like keeping all the replaces as separate actions as I did in my example just because my brain works that way, but yours is certainly less verbose and functionally should provide the same resource savings I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The first and most obvious thing that I see is that you load the file off the disk and write it back for every replace. The first optimization that I would be is to load the file into memory once, do all the replaces on it in memory, then write it back out to disk.

Something like:

```
$contents = (get-content $file) -replace '"?\|"?', "|"
$contents = $contents -replace '\|true\|', '|1|'
e
t
c
.
.
.
$contents | out-file $file
```

Comment: I like the idea, do you know the syntax for such a maneuver? As far as I know I can only replace one set of dat per get-content cycle? can I continually pipe it?

Comment: Alright, I'm going to try it out, thanks man, much appreciated.